# GitHub API Application list non public org members

Tags: github, github-api

I want to write a small application to verify members of a GitHub organisation.

The app should match the concrete GitHub org members with a database. When someone is not in the database it should remove it from the GitHub org and so on.

My Problem in using the GitHub API is, that the following request only lists public memberships (since I did not authenticate as a user, but I do not want to).

https://api.github.com/orgs/_orgname_/members?client_id=_client_id_&client_secret=_client_secret_

where *orgname*, _client_id_ and _client_secret_ are replaced with the actual organisation name and a client id/secret pair registered on this organisation.

How can I access the private members without authenticating as a user (only as an app (server2server) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't -- you need to authenticate as a user and have the right permissions. When you provide client_id and client_secret, you're still making unauthenticated requests:

https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications

And unauthenticated requests can only be used to read publicly available information.

Comment: That's what I thaught of. It's unauthenticated in means of not authenticated as a user but it is authenticated as an application. Unfortunately I don't find - and I think there isn't - a way to "give permissions to an application"

Comment: There isn't because applications can't perform any actions themselves because they don't have any permissions associated with them. Only users can perform actions on GitHub, so applications make actions on their behalf by obtaining a token with some specific permissions.

Comment: Yes and for my use case I'd require application permissions. One way would be to allocate a dummy user, but that feels terrible

Comment: Having a machine user for the purposes of automating tasks within an organization is allowed, and not something I'd call terrible. We use Hubot for such purposes internally, for example: https://github.com/hubot. You would add such an account to org teams and in that way grant it access only to some repositories and only with certain permissions (read/write/admin), in addition to being able to regulate permissions with scopes.